# How to pass model to partialview at run time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

ViewModel

```
  public class ModelTypeViewModel
  {
     public virtual  CheckRadioButton CRB { get; set; }


}
```

Controller

```
public class M1Controller : Controller
 {
    public CarContext db = new CarContext(); 

    private CheckRadioButton get()
    {
        CheckRadioButton c = new CheckRadioButton();
        c.BrandName = "abc";
        c.type = "xyz";
        return c; 

    }
  public ActionResult Hello ()
    {
        CheckRadioButton s = get();
        ModelTypeViewModel mm = new ModelTypeViewModel(s);


        return View(mm);

    }
```

View:(Hello)

```
@model Car.Models.ModelTypeViewModel
@Html.Partial("_Display", Model.CRB)
```

Partial View(_Display)

```
<h1> Hello </h1>
```

How can I pass diff model each time to to partial view?

It gives an error

> "An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpParseException' occurred in System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll but was not handled in user code"

It gives the same error even if I pass only 'Model" 
I am confused

Comment: You have to give a bit more info than just that. The code you have shown will work fine if the model your passing to the `_Display.cshtml` view is correct.

Comment: In controller : public ActionResult Hello ()
        {return view ()} 
In View:
@model Car.Models.ModelTypeViewModel
@{Html.Partial("_Display", Model.)}
In Partial View : <h1> Hi</h1> 

It's just a basic stuff, I don't know why isn't it working.

Comment: post your `Models` without it, the question can not be answered correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each button inside **Ajax.BeginForm**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BuyItem", "MsmqTest"}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "msmqpartial" }))
{ <button type="submit">Buy</button>}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BuyItem", "MsmqTest" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "msmqpartial" }))
{
    <button type="submit">Sell</button>
}
```

Where **"updateTargetId"** is the div id to append content

```
 public ActionResult BuyItem()
        {
        if(//some condition goes here)
            return PartialView("Partial1",data);
        if(//some condition goes here)
           return PartialView("Partial2",data);
        }
```

Comment: Actually I want to call different partial views for button clicks.

Comment: Updated Please Check

Comment: Thanks! But, You're using multiple action methods, I've to use single action method.

Comment: Brother,
Give same action name and put in some conditions arund partial view.See the updated code